# Control which variables get embedded inside Manipulate

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, manipulate

While trying to analyse several different datasets I got what I thought was a good idea: define a "function" that returns a `Manipulate` object. But this has some problems when larger amounts of data are passed to `Manipulate`. When the code is first run there is long delay before the manipulate pane is displayed, because the the data gets embedded inside `"Body"` of `Manipulate`.

Here is a code snippet that illustrates the problem:

```
(*Generate some data*)
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[Abs@Random[]], {5, 10^4}];
histograms = DensityHistogram[#, 30, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] & /@ data;
images = Rasterize[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ histograms;

AnalysePlots[plots_] := 
  Manipulate[plots[[i]], {i, 1, Length[plots], 1}];

(*Now compare:*)
t = AbsoluteTime[];
AnalysePlots[images] // AbsoluteTiming
AbsoluteTime[] - t
(* ==>3.7091792<---HERE IMAGES GET EMBEDDED*)

t = AbsoluteTime[];
Manipulate[images[[i]], {i, 1, Length[images], 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
AbsoluteTime[] - t

(* ==>0.0312500<---Here they don't*)
```

**Can I somehow choose whether to embed the data (in this case the variable plots) into `Manipulate`?**

When developing the function `AnalysePlots` it would be nice if I could do something like:

```
AnalysePlots[images, "Embed"->False]
```

which would have the benefit of displaying quickly. Then when I've finished `AnalyzePlots` I would deploy it with:

```
AnalysePlots[images, "Embed"->True]
```

which I could then copy and paste to a new notebook, deploy to CDF etc...

(I've already tried `SaveDefinitions->False` and `UnsavedVariables :> {plots}`)

Comment: It is something to do with defining your `Manipulates` via functions. Because this starts very quickly: **Manipulate[rasterizedSmall[[i]], {i, 1, Length[rasterizedSmall], 1}]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SetAttributes[AnalysePlots, HoldFirst]
```

and if you want to embed the images use `Evaluate`:

```
AnalysePlots[Evaluate@images]
```

Comment: +1 This indeed works. Could you comment on why it works?

Comment: @Ajasja, without setting `HoldFirst` the symbol `images` gets evaluated by `AnalysePlots`, so the call to `Manipulate` is `Manipulate[(**HUGE CHUNK OF DATA**)[[i]],...`. Setting the `HoldFirst` attribute tells `AnalysePlots` to pass `images[[i]]` through to `Manipulate` unevaluated, so the call to `Manipulate` is `Manipulate[images[[i]],...`, just as it is when you call `Manipulate` directly in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

During lunch I had an inspiration: If `SaveDefinitions-> False` is not working on named argument patters of `SetDelayed` (probably due to special scoping), then perhaps it will work on variables defined using `Module`. So the following works OK:

```
Options[AnalysePlots] = Options[Manipulate];
AnalysePlots[plots_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{aplots = plots},
  Manipulate[aplots[[i]], {i, 1, Length[aplots], 1}, opts]]

(*Now compare:*)
t = AbsoluteTime[];
AnalysePlots[images, SaveDefinitions -> False] // AbsoluteTiming
AbsoluteTime[] - t
(* ==>0.025<---no images embedded*)

t = AbsoluteTime[];
Manipulate[images[[i]], {i, 1, Length[images], 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
AbsoluteTime[] - t

(* ==>0.39<---no images embedded*)

t = AbsoluteTime[];
AnalysePlots[images, SaveDefinitions -> True] // AbsoluteTiming
AbsoluteTime[] - t
(* ==>7.045<---HERE IMAGES GET EMBEDDED*)
```