# Manipulate and Turning Expressions into Functions

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate

I've been trying to use Manipulate to do interactive plotting, but I've been running into a few problems with saved expressions. I have an expression saved as "func" and I want to work with it and then plot it later. But I can't seem to get it to work. For example, this works fine

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

while this does not

```
func = Sin[a x + b];
Manipulate[Plot[func, {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

I assume that this has something to do with when expressions are evaluated and the difference between expressions and functions, but I'm new to Mathematica and and I'm not sure on on the difference between the two.

I have tried other things like the following. For example, this works

```
Manipulate[Plot[Function[{a, b, x}, Sin[a x + b]][a, b, x], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

and this works

```
func2 = Function[{a, b, x}, Sin[a x + b]]
Manipulate[Plot[func2[a, b, x], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

but this does not

```
func = Sin[a x + b];    
func2 = Function[{a, b, x}, func];
Manipulate[Plot[func2[a, b, x], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

How could I fix this and why doesn't it work the way I have it written?

Comment: What in the last code bit is it that you thing doesn't work? It seems to work perfectly. Have you tried clearing your kernel and making sure you don't have other things interfering?

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I revised the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple straightforward way of doing this is to use `With` to inject the literal expression into the `Manipulate`.

```
func = Sin[a x + b];
With[{fun = func}, 
 Manipulate[Plot[fun, {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
]
```

You'd need to use `Dynamic@With...` if you want the manipulate to update when `func` changes.

Answer (score 8):

Just to be different:

```
func = Sin[a x + b];

func // Manipulate[Plot[#, {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is worth a new question, but why doesn't `Manipulate[
 Evaluate@Plot[Evaluate@func, {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]` work?  `Manipulate[Evaluate@func, {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]` does work as expected.

Comment: @Ajasja Imagine: what would `Plot[func, {x, 0, 6}]` evaluate to before values for `a` or `b` were provided?  How would the result of *that* be useful in a `Manipulate`?

Comment: Hmm, to an empty plot? I think I get it.

Answer (score 7):

One thing is to define the function using set delayed (rather than set). For instance

```
 func[x_, a_, b_] := Sin[a x + b];
 Manipulate[Plot[func[x, a, b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

gives an interactive plot that allows $a$ to control the frequency and $b$ to control the phase of the sinusoid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem that I am running into, however, is that I have an expression that I would like to plot saved somewhere that is not already a function proper. So, for example, I have the following, both of which do not work. Clear["`*"]
someExpression = Sin[a x + b];
func[x_, a_, b_] := someExpression
Manipulate[Plot[func[x, a, b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]

Clear[func]
func[x_, a_, b_] := Function[{x, a, b}, someExpression][x, a, b]
Manipulate[Plot[func[x, a, b], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to use formal params in your function and replace them during your manipulate:

```
func = Sin[\[Alpha] x + \[Beta]];
Manipulate[Plot[func /. {\[Alpha] -> a, \[Beta] -> b}, {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: +1 for another method.  When you say "formal" I think of formal symbols e.g. `\[FormalA]`, which might be a superior method as they cannot have values accidentally assigned.

Comment: So, to be sure I understand, `\[FormalA]` can never be assigned a value and so it works. `\[Alpha]` and the like, however, are not write protected in the same way that `a` and `b` are not protected, but still works. What is different, then, about `\[Alpha]` and `\[Beta]` that makes this work? Are they something in between regular `a` and `\[FormalA]?`

Comment: @jmbejara No, `\[Alpha]` and `\[Beta]` are just like an other symbols.  What makes this work has nothing to do with "formal symbols" but instead it is because `a` and `b` appear *explicitly* in the body of `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 5):

> ...and why doesn't it work the way I have it written?

Because `Manipulate` localizes `a` and `b`, so that the internal symbol does not match the symbol in your `func` expression.  Similarly, `Function` localizes its variables, too.

A workaround for your last example is to `Evaluate` the function body:

```
func = Sin[a x + b];
func2 = Function[{a, b, x}, Evaluate@func];
Manipulate[Plot[func2[a, b, x], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

but you can skip `func2` altogether:

```
func = Sin[a x + b];
Manipulate[Plot[Function[{a, b}, Evaluate@func][a, b], {x, 0, 6}],
 {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

`Plot` does not localize `x`, so you don't need to include it in the arguments.

Answer (score 4):

To add a little bit of variety:

```
func = Sin[a x + b];
viewExpression[exp_] := Manipulate[Plot[exp, {x, 0, 6}], {a, 1, 4}, {b, 0, 10}];
viewExpression@func
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is very similar to [Mr.W's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19928/745) answer, but uses the automatic scoping of named patterns with `SetDelayed`.

From the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html):

> ```
> When you apply a rule such as f[x_]->rhs, or use a definition such as
> f[x_]:=rhs, Mathematica implicitly has to substitute for x everywhere
> in the expression rhs. It effectively does this using the /. operator.
> As a result, such substitution does not respect scoping constructs.
> However, when the insides of a scoping construct are modified by the
> substitution, the other variables in the scoping construct are renamed.
> ```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is helpful in this application.  Can you give an example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Really? Well, thank you for pointing this out. This serves to inject an expression inside `Manipulate[Plot[...]]` just like with or a `Function` argument and is as such a direct answer. The example is the last line.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's also a useful reminder that `Manipulate` can be returned just like any other expression. (which I tended to forget when I was learning MMA). Using a pattern declaration one can also better control evaluation as I learned here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/control-which-variables-get-embedded-inside-manipulate)

Comment: I suspect that I am confused by your wording.  I read "automatic scoping of named patterns with `SetDelayed`" to refer to the automatic renaming of parameters (pattern names) in nested scoping constructs, e.g. `With[{body = x^2}, Function[x, body]]`.  I am neither seeing that behavior here nor understanding how it would help; to the contrary it would seem that this renaming, if it happened, would prevent proper function of the `Manipulate`.  If this is not what you refer to what do you mean by "automatic scoping"?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was refering to `When you apply a rule such as f[x_]->rhs, or use a definition such as f[x_]:=rhs, Mathematica implicitly has to substitute for x everywhere in the expression rhs. It effectively does this using the /. operator. As a result, such substitution does not respect scoping constructs. However, when the insides of a scoping construct are modified by the substitution, the other variables in the scoping construct are renamed` from here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html.

Comment: @Mr.W If you have a suggestion of how to improve this, please tell me or edit the answer directly.

Comment: No suggestions at this time, and a belated +1.